# Link openssl statically while building boost

Tags: c++, ssl, boost, openssl

I have built boost statically, and the archives are being linked into a shared library of my application. Into that shared library I have also linked openssl 1.1.1 archives. However, while running, the following stacktrace is produced:

```
Thread 1 (Thread 0x7fc80cc19700 (LWP 28492)):
#0  0x00007fc82d4e88c0 in TLSv1_2_enc_data () from /opt/tableau/tableau_server/packages/bin.20201.20.0326.1623/libtabssl.so.1.0.0
#1  0x00007fc82d2be41c in SSL_CTX_new () from /opt/tableau/tableau_server/packages/bin.20201.20.0326.1623/libtabssl.so.1.0.0
#2  0x00007fc7fc83effd in boost_sb::asio::ssl::context::context(boost_sb::asio::ssl::context_base::method) () from /home/employee/DrillDevelopment/NEW_DRill/lib/ThirdParty/./libdrillClient.so
#3  0x00007fc7fc830af1 in Drill::ChannelFactory::getChannelContext(Drill::channelType_t, Drill::DrillUserProperties*) () from /home/employee/DrillDevelopment/NEW_DRill/lib/ThirdParty/./libdrillClient.so
```

As you can clearly see, boost asio's ssl function picks up another, older, ssl library causing problems. I want to somehow build boost with my ssl archives included in the link. The problem is that because openssl is optional for asio, I cannot link openssl libraries to boost while building it.

Any thoughts?

EDIT1: Here is a sample link command:
 Here is a sample link command:

```
/usr/bin/g++49  -fPIC  -fPIC -O3 -DNDEBUG  -shared -Wl,-soname,libdrillClient.so -o libfoo.so -L/usr/local/lib /home/agupta/p4/AGupta_bansmbbld_3441/ThirdParty/boost/1.68.0_sb_icusb_58.2.x/_src/boost_sbdebug64/debug64/lib/libboost_sb_regex.a /home/agupta/p4/AGupta_bansmbbld_3441/ThirdParty/boost/1.68.0_sb_icusb_58.2.x/_src/boost_sbdebug64/debug64/lib/libboost_sb_system.a /home/agupta/p4/AGupta_bansmbbld_3441/ThirdParty/boost/1.68.0_sb_icusb_58.2.x/_src/boost_sbdebug64/debug64/lib/libboost_sb_date_time.a /home/agupta/p4/AGupta_bansmbbld_3441/ThirdParty/boost/1.68.0_sb_icusb_58.2.x/_src/boost_sbdebug64/debug64/lib/libboost_sb_chrono.a /home/agupta/p4/AGupta_bansmbbld_3441/ThirdParty/boost/1.68.0_sb_icusb_58.2.x/_src/boost_sbdebug64/debug64/lib/libboost_sb_thread.a /home/agupta/p4/AGupta_bansmbbld_3441/ThirdParty/boost/1.68.0_sb_icusb_58.2.x/_src/boost_sbdebug64/debug64/lib/libboost_sb_random.a /home/agupta/p4/AGupta_bansmbbld_3441/ThirdParty/openssl/1.1.1/centos5/gcc4_9/release64/lib/libssl.a /home/agupta/p4/AGupta_bansmbbld_3441/ThirdParty/openssl/1.1.1/centos5/gcc4_9/release64/lib/libcrypto.a
```

Comment: asio is header only so doesn't need to be built or linked. How are you building your shared library and application? Does it use other libraries which link to openssl? I'd recommend looking into [conan](https://conan.io) makes this sort of thing much easier

Comment: I understand that it's  header only library, however, from the call stack, you can see that the boost function is invoking SSL_CTX_new. How can I make sure that boost is built with openssl statically linked. That is, can I force that part of boost to export the symbol, so that it is fulfilled by openssl archives? Editing my post to include a sample link command

Comment: Also tried to include #include <boost/asio/impl/src.hpp> in one of my source files, and add BOOST_ASIO_SEPARATE_COMPILATION=1 to my .so build to no avail.

Comment: what about your application and other libraries? We need a [mre]